# Transferring data when identity column values are different

Tags: sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am in process of restructuring a database and creating a MVC 5 application. There are many tables which are normalized but few remains the same. In the original database table few of the rows were deleted. SO the table data looks like below,

```
Id      Column1  
--------------------
 1     Some value
 2     Some value
 4     Some value
 8     Some value
 9     Some value
```

Now I am using code first to create new database with some new and some existing database tables. In my entity model I am using the following code to mark a field as primary key and identity,

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Now the tables created by code first have auto incremented values for ID columns.

```
Id      Column1  
--------------------
 1     Some value
 2     Some value
 3     Some value
 4     Some value
 5     Some value
```

The number of records for first table are more then 100. ID column for this table is also used as foreign key in another table which has nearly 1000 records. Now problem I am facing is that how to account for the difference in the original table IDs and newly created IDs. If I try to specify the value for ID column explicitly then it gives error that I cannot explicitly specify value for Identity column. I have to write a seed method for both tables. What can be the proper way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Take a look at SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON if you need to insert specific values into identity columns.